# Get Unix Time stamp using php form dayname monthname datenumber yearnumber

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Want a proper unix time stamp from 'Wed Jan 29 2014' that format using PHP.Please Help.Thanks in advance

Comment: `echo (new DateTime('Wed Jan 29 2014'))->getTimeStamp();` or `echo strtotime('Wed Jan 29 2014');`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question, @user3472496? A simple Google search for "convert date string to timestamp php" would've pointed you in the right direction. Please read **[Ask]**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amal.But I am not a fool as you think.I tried it  but got that 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014' when I decrypt it again . dont know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$tstamp = strtotime('Wed Jan 29 2014');
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but [link](http://www.epochconverter.com/) showing 'Tue, 28 Jan 2014'. dont know why

Comment: @user3472496 You need to specify time zone. See my edit

Comment: @user3472496 Great, glad it worked for you. Can you mark the question as answered